# best way to use images in an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net website... and I want to be able to upload images to it. I will be the only one uploading, So there's no more than one user that can upload images. I am using an Access database.

If I upload the images, do I need to save the image to a folder and reference the path? Or can I upload the blob to the database and retrieve it that way in order to display it?

Whats the ups and downs of this? Will it cause the web page to take longer to load? 
And if I use the blob method, how do I display that image?

Comment: Start with the idea that your ASP.NET pages are HTML pages. This means you have to display images via 'img' tags. These tags reference the images via urls. Next question is how to make a URL that references the image in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally better to keep the files separate from DB and store just the references. There're many advantages to that like keeping DB size a lot smaller, and files are accessible for some routine operations (like virus scan).

The only advantage of keeping files in blobs is database portability - if you need to move the DB, backup or restore it - everything is in one place.

And about displaying image from a BLOB - [just Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=display%20blob%20image%20in%20asp.net).